# D3 Line Chart, Change x axis from temporal value to categorial value

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to generate a line chart where the X axis values are a string. In the example that D3 has the X axis is a date. How can I change the format of the X axis based on the example that D3 shows.

D3 example of a Line Chart
https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart

```
LineChart = // Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
// Released under the ISC license.
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart
function LineChart(data, {
  x = ([x]) => x, // given d in data, returns the (temporal) x-value
  y = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns the (quantitative) y-value
  defined, // for gaps in data
  curve = d3.curveLinear, // method of interpolation between points
  marginTop = 20, // top margin, in pixels
  marginRight = 30, // right margin, in pixels
  marginBottom = 30, // bottom margin, in pixels
  marginLeft = 40, // left margin, in pixels
  width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
  height = 400, // outer height, in pixels
  xType = d3.scaleUtc, // the x-scale type
  xDomain, // [xmin, xmax]
  xRange = [marginLeft, width - marginRight], // [left, right]
  yType = d3.scaleLinear, // the y-scale type
  yDomain, // [ymin, ymax]
  yRange = [height - marginBottom, marginTop], // [bottom, top]
  yFormat, // a format specifier string for the y-axis
  yLabel, // a label for the y-axis
  color = "currentColor", // stroke color of line
  strokeLinecap = "round", // stroke line cap of the line
  strokeLinejoin = "round", // stroke line join of the line
  strokeWidth = 1.5, // stroke width of line, in pixels
  strokeOpacity = 1, // stroke opacity of line
} = {}) {
  // Compute values.
  const X = d3.map(data, x);
  const Y = d3.map(data, y);
  const I = d3.range(X.length);
  if (defined === undefined) defined = (d, i) => !isNaN(X[i]) && !isNaN(Y[i]);
  const D = d3.map(data, defined);

  // Compute default domains.
  if (xDomain === undefined) xDomain = d3.extent(X);
  if (yDomain === undefined) yDomain = [0, d3.max(Y)];

  // Construct scales and axes.
  const xScale = xType(xDomain, xRange);
  const yScale = yType(yDomain, yRange);
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0);
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(height / 40, yFormat);

  // Construct a line generator.
  const line = d3.line()
      .defined(i => D[i])
      .curve(curve)
      .x(i => xScale(X[i]))
      .y(i => yScale(Y[i]));

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
      .call(yAxis)
      .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
      .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
          .attr("x2", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1))
      .call(g => g.append("text")
          .attr("x", -marginLeft)
          .attr("y", 10)
          .attr("fill", "currentColor")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .text(yLabel));

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", color)
      .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
      .attr("stroke-linecap", strokeLinecap)
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", strokeLinejoin)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity)
      .attr("d", line(I));

  return svg.node();
}
```

My Configuration of the Line Chart

```
<script>
    let chartTitles = document.getElementById('chart-title').innerHTML = 'Line Chart';
    let chartColor = '#d13c4b';
    let chartHeight = 500;
    let chartWidth;
    let yAxisLabel = "↑ Daily close ($)";
    let statusValues = [{status: 'PHA', value: phaCat},
                        {status: 'Local', value: localCat},];
    console.log(statusValues);
    chart = LineChart(statusValues, {
        x: d => d.status,
        y: d => d.value,
        width: chartWidth,
        height: chartHeight,
        color: chartColor,
        yLabel: yAxisLabel
      })
    console.log(chart);
    document.getElementById("d3_chart").append(chart);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Observable to try to build a line graph, then you might try their Plot library, rather than one-off code like `LineGraph`. Here's a line graph built on a categorical x-axis:

```js
let div = d3.select('#plot')

let alphabet = d3.csvParse(`letter,frequency
E,0.12702
T,0.09056
A,0.08167
O,0.07507
I,0.06966
N,0.06749
S,0.06327
H,0.06094
R,0.05987
D,0.04253
L,0.04025
C,0.02782
U,0.02758
M,0.02406
W,0.0236
F,0.02288
G,0.02015
Y,0.01974
P,0.01929
B,0.01492
V,0.00978
K,0.00772
J,0.00153
X,0.0015
Q,0.00095
Z,0.00074`, d3.autoType)

div.append(() => Plot.plot({
  height: 300,
  marks: [
    Plot.line(d3.sort(alphabet, o => o.letter), {x: 'letter', y: 'frequency'}),
    Plot.dot(d3.sort(alphabet, o => o.letter), {x: 'letter', y: 'frequency', fill: 'black'}),
  ]
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>

<div id="plot"></div>
```